# For $S$ a simple object, $\text{End}_\mathcal C(S)$ is a division ring.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal C$ a semi-simple abelian category and $S \in \mathcal C$ a simple object. I'm trying to show that $\text{End}_\mathcal C(S) = \text{Hom}_\mathcal C(S, S)$ is a division ring, i.e. each $f \in \text{End}_\mathcal C(S)$ is either $0$ or an isomorphism. This statement looks like Schur's Lemma so I though maybe use the same kind of argument to prove this but I am not able to do it. We define a simple object in $\mathcal C$ as an object $S$ such that for each monomorphism $f : X \to S$ then $f = 0$ or $f$ is an isomorphism, but how can I show that each $f \in \text{End}_\mathcal C(S)$ is at least a monomorphism ?

Comment: What can $f: S \to S$ be with your definition of simplicity ?

Comment: Maybe you can try to show that the image to, can be $S$ or $0$, what can you quotient $S$ by out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a nonzero endomorphism $f \colon S  \to S$. We then have a mono $\ker f \to S$ which is not an isomorphism, thus it must be the zero map. This shows that $f$ is mono. Using simplicity again we conclude that $f$ must be an iso.